# Traffic lights using timer

Tags: arduino-uno, c, timers

My traffic light code for the Arduino doesn't run. I was wondering if anyone could point out where my issues lie. The red and green LEDs should be on for 15 seconds and the amber on for 5 seconds.

```cpp
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdint-gcc.h>
/*15 second interrupt*/
#define INTERRUPTS 975


/* 
 * col = current colour of light. 
 * 'g', 'a', 'r', 'o'
 */
volatile uint8_t count;
volatile char col;

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    count++;
    if (count >= INTERRUPTS){
        if (col == 'g'){
            /*switch to amber*/
            col = 'a';
            /*reset counter*/
            count = 0;
            /*timer counter to 171 as we only need 85 clicks for 5s*/
            TCNT0 = 171;
            PORTD = 0b00000010;
        } else if(col == 'a'){
            col = 'r';
            count = 0;
            TCNT0 = 0;
            PORTD = 0b00000100;
        } else if (col == 'r'){
            col = 'o';
            counter = 0;
            TCNT0 = 171;
            PORTD = 0b00000010;
        } else if (col == 'o'){
            col = 'g';
            count = 0;
            TCNT0 = 0;
            PORTD = 0b00000001;
        } else{
            return;
        }
    } else{
        if(col == 'g' || col == 'r'){
            TCNT0 = 0;
        } else if(col == 'a' || col == 'o'){
            TCNT0 = 171;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    /* normal mode */
    TCCR0A = 0b00000000;
    /* prescaler = 1024 */
    TCCR0B = 0b00000101;
    /* enable overflow interrupts */
    TIMSK0 = 0b00000001;
    TCNT0 = 0;
    sei();
    /*Initialise output*/
    DDRD = 0b11111111;
    count = 0;
    col = 'g';
    PORTD = 0b00000001;
    while (1){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#define INTERRUPTS 975

volatile uint8_t count;

if (count >= INTERRUPTS){
```

`count` is an 8 bit integer, so the maximum value of it is `255`. Therefor `count` will never be bigger of equal to 975.

Use `volatile uint16_t count;` instead.

PS instead of messing with the `TCNT0` register, I'd use 2 different values of `INTERRUPTS` to change between 15 and 5 second intervals.

Something like `if( count>=975 || ( (col=='g'||col=='r') && count>=325 ) ){`

Comment: How would I time using 2 different values? Won't the 5 second count occur every time so the 15 second interrupt never occurs?

Comment: Something like `if( count>=975 || ( (col=='g'||col=='r') && count>=325 ) ){`

Comment: Ok, nice, thanks for the advice. Does everything else look ok, I won't have a board to test it again until Monday.

Comment: It would be nicer to use an enum rather than a char for the current colour. And then use a switch rather than if () {} else if () .... But those are style points rather than functionality.

Comment: Looks okay. Though I'd make it more readable. E.g. use two extra letters and change `col` to `color`.

Answer (score 1):

As far that i understand, you set the color using the Ports directly. In case green and red you set PORTD = 0b00000010;

Comment: Yes, for example to turn on the amber light I directly toggle the port so the amber LED will be turned on. If the color is currently green or red then 0b0000010; will turn on the next LED which is amber in both cases.

Comment: Ah, yes i see, my fault.

Comment: Well that's the theory anyway, but it doesn't work for some reason

Comment: And what does it do instead, is the timer not working, or does the lighth not work?

Comment: The lights are the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you want solution with a timer, I suggest to setup a 35 second cycle (35 = 15+15+5).
Then, you will trigger next LED when 0,15,30 seconds passed, and restart cycle at 35 seconds.

Other ways to achieve same effect are:
1. Use classic `delay()` function.

```
while (true)
{
    TurnOn(Green);
    delay(15000);
    TurnOn(Red);
    delay(15000);
    TurnOn(Amber);
    delay(5000);
}
```

2. use `millis()` function